# Need single return from MySQL JOIN query but getting multiple

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to list a single AccountID from an accounts table, a single client's fname, lname from a clients table.

**accounts**:
*AccountID*

**account_members**:
*AccountID,
ClientID*

**clients**:
*ClientID,
fname,
lname*

As you can see the accounts and account_members tables are related via AcccountID and the account_members and clients table are related via ClientID.

I only want to list 1 AccountID occurrence and with a single client fname & lname.

What I am getting is the AccountID multiple times depending on how many account members are listed in the account_members table.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT accounts.*, account_members.*, clients.* 
FROM accounts 
JOIN account_members ON accounts.AccountID = account_members.AccountID 
JOIN clients ON account_members.ClientID = clients.ClientID
WHERE accounts.status='Active'  
ORDER BY accounts.id DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Which member (client) do you want to get for the account ? Any member ? You basically need to group by (aggregate) on Account, instead of Distinct.

Comment: What is the significance of `LIMIT 4` here?

Comment: What's the point of `DISTINCT` if you `SELECT *`??? Probably learning some SQL will be a good start.

Comment: If you want **one** result, use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Eric There's nothing odd about select distinct \*, tables can have duplicate rows.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Comment: @philipxy `*` will include primary key, which will display every row, which will defeat the purpose of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Tables (base or subexpressions) can have duplicate rows, ie have a value that no PK could be declared for. Special cases of JOIN inputs, condition & constraints have output with no duplicates. A UNIQUE/PK of a FROM input table is not necessarily a UNIQUE/PK of the table that gets to the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to return a single value for each unique instance of AccountID, then what you want is to select a specific value from a window function.  If it doesn't matter which particular name comes back associated with the AccountID, the below query should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     FIRST_VALUE(accounts.AccountID) OVER foo,
     FIRST_VALUE(clients.fname) OVER foo,
     FIRST_VALUE(clients.lname) OVER foo
FROM accounts 
JOIN account_members ON accounts.AccountID = account_members.AccountID 
JOIN clients ON account_members.ClientID = clients.ClientID
WHERE accounts.Status = 'Active'
WINDOW foo AS (PARTITION BY accounts.AccountID);
```

If the name you return for the account does matter, you'd need to join an ordered sub-query of the `clients` table which pushes that name to the top (or bottom for last_value) rather than the clients table itself.

Comment: Unclear questions merit comments for clarification & closing, not guesses posted as answers. If you don't have the reputation to comment then wait until you do. [ask] [answer]